# Audio in html5 not working in FF4/Safari

Tags: firefox, html, html5-audio

I got this audio link in my html5 document:

```
   <audio 
      src="http://sverigesradio.se/topsy/ljudfil/3017771.m4a" 
      type="audio/mp4" 
      controls="true" 
      preload="metadata" 
      title="Senaste sändningen från Radiosporten">
   Senaste sändningen från Radiosporten</audio>
```

It renders properly in chrome, but in FF4 it first flashes the controls normally and then I get a big "X". In safari, it seems to hang while reading metadata.

Is there a problem with my audio-tag or with the audio-file? Is the redirect a problem?

Comment: Have you tried a different format? I don't recall seeing `m4a` used much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox doesn't support MP4 audio, it supports OGG audio only.

Comment: Safari supports MP3 and WAV, as bazmegakapa's link above will point out.

Comment: So I should make it explicit that safari does not support mp4 audio.

Comment: @Jonas, see http://www.scirra.com/blog/44/on-html5-audio-formats-aac-and-ogg .  Safari doesn't support Ogg, Firefox doesn't support AAC or Mp3, and IE9/10 doesn't support Ogg or wav.  Difficult situation!

Answer (score 5):

See this page for Audio support:

http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

**UPDATE**: concerning m4a format (which is AAC as far as I know), Safari and Chrome should support it, maybe even IE9, but no others.

You might find some useful info here (talks about video, but video also needs audio codecs): http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/video.html

**UPDATE 2:** And a [more up-to-date table](http://scirra.com/blog/44/on-html5-audio-formats-aac-and-ogg) posted by Tom Gullen.

Comment: I was mostly curious about m4a, which the good old html5doctor don't cover. But thanks for the link.

Comment: Baz the link is a little old now, here's an up to date table: http://www.scirra.com/blog/44/on-html5-audio-formats-aac-and-ogg

Comment: @Tom Thanks, I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox doesn't support mp4, but you can use PCM audio standard like .WAV that supports firefox, safari & chrome.